# How to show user location on XCode 4.5 simulator - prompt won't appear?

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, android-mapview

I have an MKMapView in a View Controller for my app and I checked "Shows User Location" in the Attributes tab of the MKMapView. The first simulation took awhile to load, as I expected, and the prompt came up asking whether to show the user location (Don't Allow / Allow). I chose 'Don't Allow' just to test the option first, but now the prompt will not return and I cannot show user location at all. I searched for an answer but could not find one. Sorry, I'm still a beginning iOS developer!

Thanks!

Answered below by Nico: Reset the simulator, don't be a noobie. Silly me!

Comment: Have you tried to do a reset (in the simulator, settings-> general -> reset)?

Comment: I hadn't. For some reason I thought that that had an adverse effect on my projects but I see that it's only the simulator's content. I don't feel very smart anymore! But thanks, this does the trick, although it only shows a static location that is inaccurate. I assume I'll have to actually code something for the GPS to properly work? Thanks again.

Comment: The simulator indicates only the Cupertino location, not your location. If you want to get your location, you have to hardcode it. Is it ok?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. It works now in the simulator due to the reset, thanks for the tip! Now, off to learn how to code to find the current user's location!

Comment: I add my comment as an answer. Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset your simulator permission : in the simulator -> Settings -> reset.

Comment: I can't find a Reset switch in my simulator (iOS6), but the same function can be found here:

Settings -> Privacy -> Location -> YourApp